# SHA-1 in Amazon Api Authorization in Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, amazon-s3, authorization, sha

I've been trying to get [Authorization for Amazon's s3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheCanonicalizedResourceElement) rest api going.  It's pretty damn complicated.

Because I'm trying to make a simple [GET request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) from an admin page on my website, I'm just trying to do this through Javascript.  Here are [the instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheCanonicalizedResourceElement) for constructing the Signature for the Authorization header:

```
Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign )     ))
```

To keep us sane, they give us a few examples, with the following givens:

```
var AWSSecretAccessKey = wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY,
    StringToSign = 'GET\n\n\nTue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000\n/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg;'
```

The output for this in their docs is `bWq2s1WEIj+Ydj0vQ697zp+IXMU=`.  Based on the following I am getting `ZGVjNzNmNTE0MGU4OWQxYTg3NTg0M2MxZDM5NjIyZDI0MGQxZGY0ZQ==`:

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}
```

I used [code.google.com's](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#HMAC) CryptoJS.HmacSHA1 function for the SHA1 hashing.  My final Signature function looks like this:

```
var signature = btoa( CryptoJS.HmacSHA1( aws_secret, encode_utf8( StringToSign) ) );
```

What is going wrong here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer from an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337959/need-hmac-sha1-encryption-library-for-javascript) with reference to google's older (2.0) CrytpoJs library.  You need:

- [2.0.0-crypto-sha1.js](http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/files/2.0.0-crypto-sha1.js)
- [2.0.0-hmac-min.js](http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/files/2.0.0-hmac-min.js)

Then you create your signature as so:

```
Signature = btoa( Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA1, encode_utf8(StringToSign), aws_secret, { asString: true }) )
```

I couldn't find a way to to get Strings instead of Bits in the new version.